# pg_top output analysis of puppetdb with postgres

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I recently started using a tool called pg_top that shows statistics for Postgres, however since I am not verify versed with the internals of Postgres I needed a bit of clarification on the output.

```
last pid:  6152;  load avg:  19.1,  18.6,  20.4;       up 119+20:31:38       13:09:41
41 processes: 5 running, 36 sleeping
CPU states: 52.1% user,  0.0% nice,  0.8% system, 47.1% idle,  0.0% iowait
Memory: 47G used, 16G free, 2524M buffers, 20G cached
DB activity: 151 tps,  0 rollbs/s, 253403 buffer r/s, 86 hit%, 1550639 row r/s,   
21 row w/s
DB I/O:     0 reads/s,     0 KB/s,    35 writes/s,  2538 KB/s
DB disk: 233.6 GB total, 195.1 GB free (16% used)
Swap:
```

My question is under the DB Activity, the 1.5 million row r/s, is that a lot? If so what can be done to improve it? I am running puppetdb 2.3.8, with 6.8 million resources, 2500 nodes, and Postgres 9.1. All of this runs on a single 24 core box with 64GB of memory.

Comment: 2.x is quite old. Are you being prevented from upgrading?

Comment: Yes, 2.3.8 is the highest version that is supported by puppet 3.8.x. So until we upgrade puppet along with all of the custom work that was done around it, I won't be able to use anything newer.

Comment: You might want to take this to ServerFault.